# python実践データ分析100本ノック　第３章ノック28について

Tags: python

python実践データ分析100本ノックに関する質問です。
第３章ノック28で以下のコードを実行すると「membership_period」が最初の13行を除いて全て0になってしまいます。「calc_date」,「start_date」は正常に変更されています。
なぜ「membership_period」が動作しないのか解説して頂きたいです。relativedeltaのインポートの確認もできています。
for文のインデントもできています。

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
customer_join["calc_date"] = customer_join["end_date"]
customer_join["calc_date"] = customer_join["calc_date"] .fillna(pd.to_datetime("20190430"))
customer_join["membership_period"] = 0
for i in range(len("customer_join")):
delta = relativedelta(customer_join.iloc[i,customer_join.columns.get_loc("calc_date")], customer_join.iloc[i,customer_join.columns.get_loc("start_date")])
customer_join.iloc[i,customer_join.columns.get_loc("membership_period")] = delta.years*12 + delta.months
customer_join.head()
```

Comment: [書籍のサポートページ](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/support/7980html/5875.html)から CSV ファイルなどをダウンロードして試してみましたが、`membership_period` の全てに 1 以上の値が入ります。

Comment: @metropolis さんコメントで紹介されたサンプルファイルの回答と比べると、`for`ループの3行の内容が皆少しづつ違っていますね。内容を回答と見較べるか、その前に自分で見直してみてください。なおあまり
著作権的にどうかと思われますがダウンロードしなくてもこの記事でも見ることが出来ます。[実践データ分析100本ノック(第3章-顧客の全体像を把握する-27～30)](http://houdoukyokucho.com/2020/09/27/post-1757/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。forループの3行を記事通りに以下の形に変更しても、結果は変わりませんでした。delta = relativedelta(customer_join["calc_date"].iloc[i], customer_join["start_date"].iloc[i])
    customer_join["membership_period"].iloc[i]= delta.years*12 + delta.months
customer_join.head()　　　　　ジュピターノートブックで動かしています

Comment: `for`ループの3行というのは`for`の行も含んでいますよ。DataFrame変数を記述するはずの所がDataFrame変数名の文字列になって間違っています。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、forの行を変更したところ、正確な数字を表示することができました。丁寧に対応して頂き本当にありがとうございました。